# How to make custom function has `func<type>` syntax

Tags: c++

I try to make `map`, to convert all std::string element in vector to const char *, here is my code:

```
template<typename T, typename T2, typename Func>
auto map(std::vector<T> v, Func f) {
    std::vector<T2> v2;
    for (T i: v) {
        v2.push_back(f(i));
    }
    return v2;
}
```

I wanna use it with `map<const char*>(my_vector, [](std::string v){ v.c_str()})`, how to implement the `<const char*>`

Comment: If you do such a "conversion", you need to ensure that you keep around the original "std::string" objects (and that you aren't copying them, but returning the c_str() of the originally provided strings), so that the const char* pointers are still pointing to valid memory.

Comment: Note: it is possible to do away with `T2` entirely, and have the return contained type deduced from the return type of the lambda. Change vector declaration to `std::vector<decltype(f(v[0]))> v2;`

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan can i dup c_str() to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you do it by having the parameter that you want to explicitly specify be the first template parameter:

```
template<typename T2, typename T, typename Func>
auto map(std::vector<T> v, Func f) {
    std::vector<T2> v2;
    for (T i: v) {
        v2.push_back(f(i));
    }
    return v2;
}
```

but you have to be careful in this situation, because you are passing copies of `std::string`.  You'll end up with a `vector<const char *>` which contains pointers to strings that no longer exist.

Instead, you'll need to pass a reference:

```
template<typename T2, typename T, typename Func>
auto map(std::vector<T> &v, Func f) { // pass by reference here
    std::vector<T2> v2;
    for (T& i: v) { // take by reference here
        v2.push_back(f(i));
    }
    return v2;
}
```

and have your lambda take a reference as well:

```
[](std::string &v){ return v.c_str(); }
```

Comment: @M.M: Indeed.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand "you'll end up with a vector<const char *> which contains pointers to strings that no longer exist.", when I use [this code](https://gist.github.com/f5635cc0ea25a052fcd2), I can get `v` and `v2`, what 's wrong with that?

Comment: @asullaherc: In that code, you aren't using the values of v2, so it doesn't really matter, but if you were, it would be a problem.

Comment: "which contains pointers to strings that no longer exist.", when will pointers be no longer exist, can you expand you answer, I don't understand

Comment: I have use strdup in my [code](https://gist.github.com/122db1496dc25bd31136), does it still has problem?

Comment: @asullaherc: If you use strdup that will avoid the dangling pointers.  Just be sure to `free()` them once you are done.